# Trigger value change in json from ng repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have Following Json:

```
{
    "FunctionIs": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "Type": "A"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test2",
        "Type": "A"
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Test3",
        "Type": "A"
    },{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Test4",
        "Type": "A"
    },{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Test5",
        "Type": "B"
    },{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Test6",
        "Type": "B"
    },{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Test7",
        "Type": "C"
    },{
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Test8",
        "Type": "C"
    },]
}
```

I am populating these values through ng-repeat in my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="businessdata in userObj.businessJson">
    <td id="idIs">{{businessdata.id}}</td>
    <td>{{businessdata.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Whenever there is change in "Type" (From A to B and B to C and C to D and so on), I want to insert a new `<tr>` for displaying the heading(Type) only for the first time. Can anyone help in this?
Thanks!

Comment: What you tried for this?

Comment: Where you change the type?

Comment: The Type is coming from JSON, I need to just trigger the condition when the Type Changes.

Comment: @RituG.Vijaywargiya by type change you mean **string to int**

Comment: No, by Type I meant the key in Json as there in problem

Answer (score 1):

You could create create 3 different `ng-repeat` each for different type.

e.g.

```
<tr><th>A</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {Type:'A'}">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><th>B</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {Type:'B'}">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><th>C</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {Type:'C'}">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RxoG9LUbeuQbMW1leosa?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to reiterate my code again and again, since this is just the example, my actual code has 8-10 types and I want to make it Generic. Do you have any other solution where we can just put condition for targeting the JSON change?